# Heatmap fusion table only shows 1 latitude longitude point

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables, heatmap

This is the link to my fusion table of latitude and longitude points: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=15fqwXO49M-kIOrHVSfE8J4yVsfuD4ySEkZ28494#rows:id=1

I am trying to create a heat map using latitude and longitude points and for some reason only 1 point is displayed.

```
Here is my code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Flickr Data Visualization Map</title>

<style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>


  var map;


  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
      zoom: 3,
      maxZoom: 20,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });




 var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
  select: 'Location',
  from: '15fqwXO49M-kIOrHVSfE8J4yVsfuD4ySEkZ28494'
},
  heatmap: {
  enabled: true
  }
});
 layer.setMap(map);

}   

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see more than one point, but the heatmap certainly only covers one area (around San Diego), where there is obviously data in other places.

Comment: Independent of the heatmap problem, the code selects 'Location' but there is no such column in the table.

Comment: 'Location' is the column type. I copied the example on google's developer site: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-heatmap?hl=fr

Comment: possible duplicate of [heat map using lat long points from google spread sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037218/heat-map-using-lat-long-points-from-google-spread-sheet)

Comment: Please don't add duplicates to push your question. Question is flagged now. Read the [help] and see [ask].