# heat map using lat long points from google spread sheet

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-sheets, heatmap

Here is a link to my Google spread sheet with lat long points: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Av4n0ReFCN-PdGFISEF0MFRmSDNkTTRlVml2dTJwQ0E#gid=0

I followed this Google developer tutorial on YouTube on how to add markers from points in Google spread sheets: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OS2Nj5G9cGs

It worked, I was able to add markers for all of my points. Now, I need to make a heatmap using those same points. It only seems to put a few points around 1 area on the map.

EDITED CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Flickr Data Visualization Map</title>

<style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,visualization&sensor=true"></script>

<script>
  // The web service URL from Drive 'Deploy as web app' dialog.
  var DATA_SERVICE_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwrkOm22MKwgTvbrtMUtUc6qDwAfnA_rCCua2RGtLRYtUPGwRA/exec?jsonp=callback";

  var map;
  var heatmapData = [ ];

  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
      zoom: 3,
      maxZoom: 20,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.src = DATA_SERVICE_URL;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
  }

function callback(data) {

    var heatmapData = [ ];

   for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    heatmapData.push( new google.maps.LatLng( data[i][0], data[i][1] ) );
}


var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer( {
    data : heatmapData

} );


 }

</script>
</head>

  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use jsFiddle for an example. And do some `console.log()` to see where it stops.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem just is how you push data to the array: You're basically resetting the array on each iteration. Use `.push()` instead.

```
function callback( data ) {
    var headmapData = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        heatmapData.push( new google.maps.LatLng( data[i][0], data[i][1] ) );
    }

    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer( {
        data : heatmapData
    } );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post. :) I edited the code as you suggested, and now all it does is display a blank map. I posted the edited code in my original question above.